# Does anyone know a library that can emulate 3 throttles?

Tags: library, arduino-micro

There is [this library](https://github.com/MHeironimus/ArduinoJoystickLibrary), but it emulates only one throttle and one rudder. The X Y Z axis don't work because they are addressed from -127 to 127 and I need 0 to 255. I just need one more throttle axis. If it helps, I'm using an ATmega328 and read analog values in the 0 to 1024 range to read Logitech g27 pedals, then dividing by about 4 to fit the read value into the 0 to 255 range.

Comment: We really want questions here to be self contained and not depend on external links for their key parts, but conversion from a -127 to 127 range to a 0-255 one should be straightforward - just add an offset.

Comment: I agree with Chris the axis ought to work if you modify the value in your code, but if there is a reason you can't use them could you not just create a private version of the library an add in the necessary for an extra throttle, pin, variable and function? (Can't see the code, can't be more specific). Maybe the author would be interested in it for joystick4.